# Removing punctuation except for apostrophes AND intra-word dashes in R

Tags: string, r, text

I know how to separately remove punctuation and keep apostrophes:

```
gsub( "[^[:alnum:]']", " ", db$text )
```

or how to keep intra-word dashes with the tm package:

```
removePunctuation(db$text, preserve_intra_word_dashes = TRUE)
```

but I cannot find a way to do both at the same time. For example if my original sentence is:

```
"Interested in energy/the environment/etc.? Congrats to our new e-board! Ben, Nathan, Jenny, and Adam, y'all are sure to lead the club in a great direction next year! #obama #swag"
```

I would like it to be:

```
"Interested in energy the environment etc Congrats to our new e-board Ben Nathan Jenny and Adam y'all are sure to lead the club in a great direction next year obama swag"
```

Of course, there will be extra white spaces, but I can remove them later.

I will be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 10):

Use [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

```
gsub("[^[:alnum:]['-]", " ", db$text)

## "Interested in energy the environment etc Congrats to our new e-board Ben Nathan Jenny and Adam y'all are sure to lead the club in a great direction next year obama swag"
```

Comment: Thank you for the short and nice solution. It works perfectly well on a small sample of tweets I have, but when I run it on a sample of over 200,000 tweets I get an error: could not find function "&<-". Do you have any idea what this might relate to? I don't suppose I need to download any additional package, do I?

Comment: I have no idea what is this error cause by. I think it comes from other part of your code. And no, `gsub` is base R, no need in additional packages

Comment: You are so right, thank you - a stupid typo of course.

Comment: Unfortunately this method does not differentiate between intra-word dashes and between word dashes. In a string: string1<- "dash should be kept here: e-mail but not here: e - mail" it keeps both dashes. I'm playing with regex now to try to keep only intra-word dashes but if you have any advice, that would be very helpful.

Comment: I figured it out with 2 steps: first remove between-word dashes: gsub(" - ", " ", string1,perl = TRUE), then use the above solution.

Answer (score 3):

I like `David Arenberg's` answer. If you need another way, you could try:

```
library(qdap)

text <- "Interested in energy/the environment/etc.? Congrats to our new e-board! Ben, Nathan, Jenny, and Adam, y'all are sure to lead the club in a great direction next year! #obama #swag"

gsub("/", " ",strip(text, char.keep=c("-","/"), apostrophe.remove=F,lower.case=F))
#[1] "Interested in energy the environment etc Congrats to our new e-board Ben Nathan Jenny and Adam y'all are sure to lead the club in a great direction next year obama swag"
```

or

```
library(gsubfn)
 clean(gsubfn("[[:punct:]]", function(x) ifelse(x=="'","'",ifelse(x=="-","-"," ")),text))
#[1] "Interested in energy the environment etc Congrats to our new e-board Ben Nathan Jenny and Adam y'all are sure to lead the club in a great direction next year obama swag"
```

`clean` is from `qdap`.  Used to remove escaped characters and space