# Replacing punctuation except intra-word dashes with a space

Tags: python, regex, r

There already is an approaching [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24550620/removing-punctuation-except-for-apostrophes-and-intra-word-dashes-in-r) in R `gsub("[^[:alnum:]['-]", " ", my_string)`, but it does not work in Python:

```
my_string = 'compactified on a calabi-yau threefold @ ,.'
re.sub("[^[:alnum:]['-]", " ", my_string)
```

gives `'compactified on a calab yau threefold  @ ,.'`

So not only does it remove the intra-word dash, it also removes the last letter of the word preceding the dash. And it does not remove punctuation

Expected result (string without any punctuation but intra-word dash): `'compactified on a calabi-yau threefold'`

Comment: `[:alnum:]` matches alphanumeric strings. Why not just use `r'[^\w['-]'` in Python?

Comment: I don't know I am completely regex illiterate

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you want to do.

Comment: why would one thing work in R but not in Python - anyway let me try your proposition

Comment: @Alex how can I be more explicit than what the title of my question says?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `"r'[^\w['-]"` does not remove the intra-word dash, which is nice, but it does not remove punctuation at all

Comment: But `[:alnum:]` matches letters and digits. It does not match punctuation. Try [`r"[^\w\['-]"`](https://regex101.com/r/pE3aI8/1). Or more similar (since it will exclude `_`): `r"[^\w_\['-]"`

Comment: You can use this http://pythex.org/ for testing

Comment: @EnriquePérezHerrero thanks

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `[^\w\['-]` seems to give me what I want. Thanks (feel free to make it an answer)

Comment: Do you want to retain or remove underscores, e.g. One_two

Comment: @Alexander they should be removed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

R uses TRE (POSIX) or PCRE regex engine depending on the `perl` option (or function used). Python uses a modified, much poorer Perl-like version as `re` library. Python does not support *POSIX character classes*, as **[`[:alnum:]`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html)** that matches *alpha* (letters) and *num* (digits).

In Python, `[:alnum:]` can be replaced with `[^\W_]` (or ASCII only `[a-zA-Z0-9]`) and the negated `[^[:alnum:]]` - with `[\W_]` (`[^a-zA-Z0-9]` ASCII only version).

The `[^[:alnum:]['-]` matches *any 1 symbol other than alphanumeric (letter or digit), `[`, `'`, or `-`*. **That means the R question you refer to does not provide a correct answer**.

You can use the [following solution](http://ideone.com/m2OdLQ):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r"(\b[-']\b)|[\W_]")
test_str = "No -  d'Ante compactified on a calabi-yau threefold @ ,."
result = p.sub(lambda m: (m.group(1) if m.group(1) else " "), test_str)
print(result)
```

The [`(\b[-']\b)|[\W_]` regex](https://regex101.com/r/bS5cY6/1) matches and captures intraword `-` and `'` and we restore them in the `re.sub` by checking if the capture group matched and re-inserting it with `m.group(1)`, and the rest (all non-word characters and underscores) are just replaced with a space.

If you want to remove sequences of non-word characters with one space, use

```
p = re.compile(r"(\b[-']\b)|[\W_]+")
```

Comment: Finally, checked the negated alnum correlation between POSIX and Python regexes. Added to the answer. Note that `\w`/`\W` versions will work with all Unicode letters well (if you add the `re.UNICODE` flag).

Comment: just one thing: I noticed that `'` and `[` are not removed: see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/pE3aI8/1)

Comment: Perhaps, you should use `r"[\W_+['-]"` (after my final edit, I did not update the final pattern) I will add a Python demo now.

Comment: actually, dashes that stand alone are kept - they should be removed as they are punctuation marks (only intra-word dashes should be kept)

Comment: Are you interested in ASCII only?

Comment: I just want to remove all punctuation marks except intra-word dashes

Comment: That means the R question you refer to does not give a proper answer (it is incorrect). I "converted" it correctly, but the results are not expected as the R pattern is wrong.

Comment: What is the expected output for `No - d'Ante compactified on a calabi-yau threefold @ ,.`? `No   d'Ante compactified on a calabi-yau threefold     `?

Comment: from `No - d'Ante ' compactified on a calabi-yau threefold @ ,.?` I'd like to get `No d'Ante compactified on a calabi-yau threefold`

Comment: Then, I think my current answer should work for you.