# strip and split how to strip the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, split, strip

my code:

```
readfile = open("{}".format(file), "r")

lines = readfile.read().lower().split()

elements = """,.:;|!@#$%^&*"\()`_+=[]{}<>?/~"""
for char in elements:
    lines = lines.replace(char, '')
```

this works and removes the special characters. but I need help with striping "-" and " ' "

so for example " saftey-dance " would be okay but not " -hi- "   but " i'll " is okay but not " 'hi "

i need to strip only the beginning and ending

its not a string it is a list.

how do I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Removing punctuation except intra-word dashes Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35613990/removing-punctuation-except-intra-word-dashes-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stripping everything but alphanumeric chars from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276764/stripping-everything-but-alphanumeric-chars-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: its not a string, its a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, using `str.replace` in a loop is inefficient. Since strings are immutable, you would be creating a need string on each of your iterations. You can use `str.translate` to remove the unwanted characters in a single pass.

As to removing a dash only if it is not a boundary character, this is exactly what `str.strip` does.

It also seems the characters you want to remove correspond to `string.punctuation`, with a special case for `'-'`.

```
from string import punctuation

def remove_special_character(s):
    transltation = str.maketrans('', '', punctuation.replace('-', ''))
    return ' '.join([w.strip('-') for w in s.split()]).translate(transltation)

polluted_string = '-This $string contain%s ill-desired characters!'
clean_string = remove_special_character(polluted_string)

print(clean_string)

# prints: 'This string contains ill-desired characters'
```

If you want to apply this to multiple lines, you can do it with a list-comprehension.

```
lines = [remove_special_character(line) for line in lines]
```

Finally, to read a file you should be using a `with` statement.

```
with open(file, "r") as f
    lines = [remove_special_character(line) for line in f]
```

Comment: @guide I also added a recommendation as to how to open a file safely with a with statement, I recommend you read it.

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try `string.punctuation` and `strip`:

```
import string

my_string_list = ["-hello-", "safety-dance", "'hi", "I'll", "-hello"]

result = [item.strip(string.punctuation) for item in my_string_list]
print(result)
```

Result:

```
['hello', 'safety-dance', 'hi', "I'll", 'hello']
```